# ViewerJS not loading my pdf document

Tags: html

As said in the instructions at the site [ViewerJS Instructions](http://viewerjs.org/instructions/), I tried to embed my file like `http://localhost/site/ViewerJS#../docs/mydoc.pdf`

But this is not working. 
My document is in the dir like 
`/docs/mydoc.pdf` and a link like `http://localhost/site/docs/mydoc.pdf` is working perfectly. In href, I usually put `docs/mydoc.pdf` and that works. In the same way, as said in the instructions, my document is not loading.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple. Move the `ViewerJS` to the root directory of the site. Everything is working perfectly.

So, the viewer is accessible like
`http://localhost/site/ViewerJS/#../docs/mydoc.pdf`